# Custom Keyboard Layout only works on MacBooks screen, not on external ones!

Tags: keyboard, display, monterey

I just installed https://github.com/patrick-zippenfenig/us-with-german-umlauts since I kind of need it because I am used to it. It works perfectly fine, as long as my mouse´s focus is on the MacBook´s own display. It stops working as soon as I am working on an external Display (Samsung 5K G9 if that matters).

This behavior applies to both, the MacBooks own keyboard as well as my bluetooth external one.

It is a MacBook Pro 14" with Monterey 12.0. Also, I noticed that my keyboard icon isn´t working on the top right. So it looks like I got two Keyboard Layouts set up, depending on the display focusd.

Does someone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you reached out to the developer and asked about this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can show the keyboard icon in the menu bar by going into `System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources` and enabling `Show input menu in menu bar`.

Sometimes, if you have multiple keyboard layouts enabled, macOS switches them automatically when you switch between apps or windows, which probably happens when you change the focus to a different display.

When this happens, you can switch back manually to your desired layout via the input menu. Alternatively, you can disable this behavior by unchecking `Automatically switch to a document's input source`, also in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources`.

Comment: It is hard to see any connection between your answer and the question, which asks why a custom keyboard layout is not working on an external display.

Comment: @TomGewecke macOS might be automatically switching the keyboard layout when the focus changes from an app in the built-in display to a different app or window in the external display. Sorry for not mentioning that explicitly in my answer.